How to use Jackson serialization to deserialize CSV file, but one line at a time?
This article shows how to deserialize CSV using jackson. Shown way:
CsvSchema headerSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
String CSV_WITH_HEADER = ...; // see example above
MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> it = mapper
  .readerFor(Point.class)
  .with(headerSchema)
  .readValues(CSV_WITH_HEADER);

reads whole file at once, meaning, that if I have 10 lines and mistake on 5th, I will get the error, but I won't know on which line, and memory requirements will be higher. I tried to read it line by line, but that's not possible either, since it detaches lines and csv header. And I cannot just skip the header, since the ordering might be different. And I especially don't want to use ordinal number of column to map it to some POJO field.
Is there a simple way how to read annotated POJOs from CSV, with failure per line?
Cheat way how to do it: read input using BufferedReader line by line. First read line is header, then for every other line create fake 2-liner input prepending current line with header line, and read it as shown in article. Works, very ugly.

You wrote (in your question): I will get the error Pardon me, but what error are you referring to? I don't see details of any error in your question. Or is the actual error irrelevant? By the way, shouldn't you add the "java" tag to your question?

@Abra any error related to the line. wrong datatype, bad number of columns on that line, anything
